# Want to call a Rest POST endpoint with retries using a circuitBreaker

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I am running a test from job which makes a http POST submission to 3rd party REST endpoint and implemented retry using `requestHandlerAdvice` with `backoffpolicy` policy set as `exponential`. I was thinking is there a way to implement `circuitBreaker` with `requestHandlerAdvice` . The reason for this is if after couple of retries message fails , then circuit shall remain open and after some threshold when I retry with post request and I get a response, I will resume Post submissions to 3rd party REST endpoint

Answer (score 1):

The framework provides [both retry and circuit breaker advices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Simply add both to the request handler advice chain.

Comment: Meanwhile Gary is right, let me ask additional info or rephrase: do you want to open circuit breaker for all other requests to the endpoint meanwhile the current one is retrying?

Comment: You have led to even more questions :) . Currently I was trying to send each request synchronously. Let me ask another question to you: How could you make parallel sync calls . Being a newbie to this, I believe Routers would be used. Please enlighten me :)

Comment: Thanks @garyRussel for the reply